# The catalyst of the thoughts

Tags: riddle

I was always with the wisest
who because of me made this earth the best.

You are gonna find me in the end
With someone who is always there with me to stand

I am the catalyst of the thoughts
When you don't know something, I will always be there

When you find me,
I will be sure it is because of my enemy,

But do you even know who is me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is

> **Question**

---

**Explanation as Follows**

---

I was always with the wisest

who because of me made this earth the best.

> Wise people always has questions and those questions lead them to the answers which resulted in inventions

You are gonna find me in the end

> There is a question at the end of the riddle i.e. "But do you even know who is me?"

With someone who is always there with me to stand

> I think it's referring to the question mark (?) that always stands with a question at the end of the question.

I am the catalyst of the thoughts

When you don't know something, I will always be there

> Questions provoke thoughts to find the answer. When we don't know something, there will definitely arises a question (What is it? How is it? etc)

When you find me,

I will be sure it is because of my enemy,

> When we find the answer. which is 'Question', it's because of the enemy of 'question' which is answer (answer is the antonym of question.

Comment: right answer but explaination of a paragraph is incorrect. correct it and i will accept the answer.

Comment: Is it the second para?

Comment: Come on buddy u can find it out yourself, can't you?

Comment: I will try finding it and fixing

Comment: Updated the answer. Am I correct now?

Comment: nope...still not the correct explanation :(

Comment: I think maybe an explanation for "always there with me to stand" may be a <answer> mark?